# Looping through directories in proc

Tags: c, linux, proc

I have a function which loops through the directories in the proc file system. This function then greps a process name to find its PID and returns this PID to the calling function.

The function seems to work fine but fails in one or two cases while opening some directory(corresponding to a process).
This is what I am doing.

```
 dr = readdir(dp);
```

Loop through dr 
Check dr type for directory and process name 
compare the process name with a string.

```
 Return PID in case of a match 
 dr = readdir(dp);
 end loop 



main() {
   DIR *d;
   struct dirent *e;

   e=malloc(sizeof(struct dirent));
   d=opendir("/proc");

   while ((e = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
      printf("%d %s\n", e->d_type, e->d_name);
   }

   closedir(d);
}
```

Comment: When you say "fails in one or two cases" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Don't forget that C these days expects return types on functions such as `main()`, and the return type should be `int`. Unless you've got a C99 or newer compiler, which should insist on the explicit `int` return type on `main()`, it is not safe to leave off `return(0);` or equivalent from the end of `main()`; C89 did not give you that licence.  Surely, each of the 'all numeric' directory names in `/proc` is a PID; you don't need to access anything in the directory to determine the PID for reporting back to the user.

Comment: I know this but your point is not focusing on the core of the problem.

Comment: @Chimera: When I run this program in an infinite loop, I get error, sometimes after a couple of hours even when the process which I am trying to grep is running properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably the problem is that directories are disappearing before you get to check out the files inside. This would mean that a process that was running when you go the directory listing is no longer running when you go to read its process information. This is normal and something you'll have to handle (ideally silently) in your application.

Also, the code snippet you provided definitely does not do what you described above it. Presumably you edited it for simplicity, but in doing so you removed any clues as to what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks.. I think this is what is happening. Since proc keeps on changing dynamically, this is possible. Yes, I have provided a small code snippet in order to keep the post simple... Thanks a lot. I think, the error will have to handled silently.